# Filter index and Hash functions in Bloom Filter

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, probability

Bloom filter uses a bit array of m-bits hence there are 0 to m-1 indexes in the array but the hash functions I'm using return a 32-bit hash hence it could be from 0 to (2^32)-1 as the hash is used as an index for the bit array(filter) it is quite possible that the hash is greater than m as a result the value will not be mapped on the bit array. Should I take the mod of the hash i.e **hash % m** so that the resulting hash must correspond to an index in the bit array. Will it increase the number of false positives(IMO it will)?

Comment: Don't do mod.  Simply use the first m bits of the hash function.  The odds of a false positive do depend on how many bits you use, but so too does space used.  The whole point of a bloom filter is that you get to choose the tradeoff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hash function `h: S -> uint` is loosely defined to be one which exhibits a high degree of entropy over the set `S`.  Suppose I have a certain hash function `h` that has very high entropy over `S`, but for which the output `h(x)` for `x` in `S` is always even. This restriction simply means that a bit of the output of `h` is being wasted, which is only `1 / 32` of the bits.

Now suppose I have a Bloom filter for which `m` is an even number. Then `h(x) % m` is always going to be an even number - which means *only half of the bits of the Bloom filter will ever be used!* That's bad!

As others have suggested, simply taking the first `m` bits of `h(x)` as an index into `2^m` Bloom filter bins is a better strategy, because, assuming you're being given a hash function that exhibits a high degree of entropy over the set `S`, the "first `m` bits" hash function `g(x) = h(x)[0:m-1]` should exhibit a nearly proportional amount of entropy.

Comment: okay. if I use the first **n** bits of a hash in that case the size of the bit array should be **2^n** i.e the maximum index would be **(2^n)-1** so that every possible hash is a valid index?

Comment: @AbdullahSaleem For a Bloom filter with `2^m` bins, you would use the first `m` bits of `h(x)`, interpreted as an unsigned binary integer, as the index into the Bloom filter bins.

Comment: that is understood but what if the length of the Bloom filter is not **2^m**. for example the length of the bloom filter is **50**. I can't use the first **5 bits** because the resulting hash would be from **0-31** and I can't use first **6 bits** because in this case the resulting hash would be from **0-63**

Comment: @AbdullahSaleem Often you are choosing the number of bins in the Bloom filter yourself, so this is usually a non-issue. If you want to use `n` bins you can pick a large prime number like `p = 19937` such that `p` is much greater than `n` and then use `(h(x) % p) % n` to compute the bin for `x`. This could *potentially* still have problems, although in practice you probably wouldn't encounter them. (The rationale is that, *assuming* `h(x) % p` *is uniformly distributed*, `(h(x) % p) % n` maps your values `x` almost-uniformly, off by one, which is negligible in a Bloom filter.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using mod increases probability for false positives. Stephan T. Lavavej had a great talk about it on GoingNative 2013 (that **mod** creates bias), See [HERE](http://youtu.be/LDPMpc-ENqY?list=PL09Ke5-ligfmlkBZRHA3HbEQSU2LanWti)

His also mentioning about (what @btilly) said: it's better to simply cut bits - if yours hash function is good then it's OK.